I do not get how camera sizing works
I'm following a tutorial to learn how to use unity, but at the "Logic and UI" part I had issues implementing text.
In order for a score to be shown at the top right of my screen, I have to make the text size very small, therefore only being able to use a small font size (ca. 12), which results in a awful quality.
I do not understand why my sprite (800 x 800) fits nicely into the frame, but the font needs to be tiny.
Considering that under Game, I have 1920x1080 selected and the bird sprite fits, I was expecting the text box to be able to be larger than 10x10 even if it was only ment for the top right. (And a simialr font size as in the tutorial [abt. 111])
Text settings (Text poor quality but bird looks fine)
Settings for Main Cam

did you try making the text area bigger, so it would take bigger size font?

@BugFinder Yes, but if I made the text box big enough for the font to look good, then it would take up the entire camera. Then i'd have to increase the Camera scale, and then all the sprites. What I don't understand is, if the camera is so small, that proper-sized font does not fit, why does a 800x800 sprite fit with no problem?

The first problem is that you're using the legacy Text component instead of TextMeshPro (it's marked legacy for a reason)

@GuyIncognito, I'm new so I don't know what the difference is. All I know is that in this tutorial  he uses Legacy Text and when I try TextMeshPro, I can't reference the Text in my Script.

Time to learn then. TextMeshPro is not Text so you can't use Text to reference it.

Ok, but then how come Legacy Text is such low quality? /Works so poorly

The Legacy component has nothing to do with this. Sure it's not as high quality as TMPro, but in this case, your problem is that you're viewing the Text in the scene view and the Canvas is Overlay. What you want to look at to see the final result is the Game View as the UI is rendered properly on top of existing sprites rendered in the correct size/resolution by the camera. Overlay Canvas tends to have huge elements if seen in scene view. You could mess with the canvas and make it screen space, assign the camera and set the depth to match the UI with what you see of your level in scene view.

Also from your first screenshot, I can see you are placing that Text outside of the Canvas so it won't show in the Game View.
